# does vkontakte newsfeed search support boolean operators?

Tags: vk, booleanquery

For example for:

```
https://api.vk.com/method/newsfeed.search.json?q=moscow
```

What can I do with the search query?
Does it support AND, OR, etc?
Can I specify exact terms in quotes, e.g. 
    q="Big Ben" ?
Is there a page where this is documented?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Search terms are split on whitespace and they are AND'd together. Quoted terms are treated as a phrase. There is no support for OR or NOT logic.