# VK newsfeed.search -- search string not respecting " " for exact term search

Tags: vk

When using newsfeed.search to search, with q = "UEFA EL", we are finding the exact term search to be ignored. We get response that has keyword "UEFA" and "EL", but not as a phrase but separated.

Is VK newsfeed.search respecting the exact term search?

```
https://api.vk.com/method/newsfeed.search?v=5.69&q=%22UEFA%20EL%22&count=200&start_time=1618441503&access_token=[access_token]
```

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/q/28782164/42346

Comment: No, we are using the quotation, so the search should be exact phrase, but what we see is different result. So looks to be different problem.